# Item do Qml em posição fixa

Tags: teclado, posicionamento, qml

Os dispositivos móveis movem os elementos para cima quando o teclado é chamado, mas existem elementos que ficam na mesma posição quando o teclado do dispositivo é chamado como nas imagens abaixo.

Como eu posso manter um item de Qml fixo na posição quando o teclado do dispositivo é chamado?

Preciso que o `Rectangle` com `id: principal` fique fixo na posição

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3

Window {
    visible: true

    property int larguraTela: 360
    property int alturaTela: 640

    width: larguraTela
    height: alturaTela

    maximumWidth: larguraTela
    maximumHeight: alturaTela

    minimumWidth: larguraTela
    minimumHeight: alturaTela

    title: "OverStatusBar"

    Rectangle {
        id: principal

        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height * 0.15

        anchors.top: parent.top

        color: "orange"
    }

    Rectangle {

        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height * 0.85

        anchors.top: principal.bottom

        clip: true

        Rectangle{
            id: retangulo1

            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height * 0.5

            anchors.top: parent.top

            color: "grey"
        }

        Rectangle {
            id: retangulo2

            width: parent.width
            height: parent.height * 0.5

            anchors.top: retangulo1.bottom

            color: "lightgrey"

            TextField {
                id: campoTexto

                width: parent.width * 0.7
                height: parent.height * 0.20

                anchors.centerIn: parent

                inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhDigitsOnly

            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image] [image]

Comment: Teria como mandar o print do Xcode?

Comment: Não estou usando XCode, estou usando Qml.

Comment: Editei o post para inserir o código fonte.

Comment: Não apareceu ainda.

Comment: Eu estava procurando uma solução para o problema e lendo alguns sites vi que o que eu estou procurando é um Qml Type que funcione como a barra de navegação do iOS. Há algum elemento em Qml que faça isto. Eu tentei o StackView, mas ele continua se movendo para cima quando o teclado aparece.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, depois de uma longa pesquisa sobre este tópico eu conclui que não há solução possível, pelo menos até agora, que não envolva muita programação alternativa para resolver o problema em linguagens multi-plataforma. Eu tentei várias linguagens multi-plataforma sem encontrar nenhuma solução satifatória que pudesse ser implementada. As linguagens que eu tentei foram:

- QML
- Appcelerator (Titanium)
- PhoneGap (Cordova)
- Native Script
- React Native

Minha conclusão é que se eu quiser desenvolver apps com aparência e comportamento nativos que funcionem como o esperado e sem bugs, eu preciso fazer isto utilizando as linguagens de programação nativas, mesmo que eu precise desenvolver duas vezes em linguagens diferentes. É o que eu estou fazendo a partir de agora: XCode and Android Studio.

Se alguém quiser dar uma olhada em um pedaço de código para começar a fazer isto em QML acesse o link [clicando aqui](http://forum.qt.io/topic/62365/qml-item-fixed-positioning/14):

> I have something very hackish and begging for refinement but I think it is going into the right direction :
>
> ```
> import QtQuick 2.4
> import QtQuick.Window 2.2
> import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
> Window {
>     visible: true
>     property int larguraTela: 360
>     property int alturaTela: 640
>     width: larguraTela
>     height: alturaTela
>     maximumWidth: larguraTela
>     maximumHeight: alturaTela
>     minimumWidth: larguraTela
>     minimumHeight: alturaTela
>     title: "OverStatusBar"
>     Rectangle {
>         id: principal
>         width: parent.width
>         height: parent.height * 0.15
>         anchors.top: parent.top
>         color: "orange"
>     }
>     Timer{
>         id:resetKeyboard
>         interval: 500
>         onTriggered: {
>             Qt.inputMethod.hide();
>             Qt.inputMethod.show();
>             unlock.restart();
>         }
>     }
>     Timer{
>         id:unlock
>         interval: 500
>
>         onTriggered: {
>             flickable.updateSlideContent = true;
>         }
>     }
>
>     Flickable{
>         id:flickable
>         width: parent.width
>         height : slideContent ? parent.height * 0.5 : parent.height * 0.85
>         anchors.top: principal.bottom
>         clip: true
>         contentHeight: parent.height * 0.85
>         contentY : slideContent ? parent.height*0.35 : 0
>
>         property bool updateSlideContent : true
>         property bool slideContent : false
>         property bool keyboardVisible : Qt.inputMethod.visible
>         onKeyboardVisibleChanged: {
>             if (updateSlideContent) {
>                 slideContent = keyboardVisible;
>                 if (keyboardVisible)
>                 {
>                     updateSlideContent = false;
>                     resetKeyboard.restart();
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>
>         Rectangle {
>
>             anchors.fill: parent
>
>
>
>
>             Rectangle{
>                 id: retangulo1
>
>                 width: parent.width
>                 height: parent.height * 0.5
>
>                 anchors.top: parent.top
>
>                 color: "grey"
>             }
>
>             Rectangle {
>                 id: retangulo2
>
>                 width: parent.width
>                 height: parent.height * 0.5
>
>                 anchors.top: retangulo1.bottom
>
>                 color: "lightgrey"
>
>                 TextField {
>                     id: campoTexto
>
>                     width: parent.width * 0.7
>                     height: parent.height * 0.20
>
>                     anchors.centerIn: parent
>
>                     inputMethodHints: Qt.ImhDigitsOnly
>
>                 }
>             }
>         }
>
>     }
> }
> ```